# MaintainScrollPosition not working on mobile browsers after upgrading from .Net 2.0 to .Net 4.0

Tags: .net, browser, maintainscrollpositionon

On a mobile browser, a user would zoom in and click a button. After the postback, the page would return to the same position and zoom as before. However, when the site was upgraded to .Net 4.0, the page loses the position and zoom on a postback. If this functionality is lost in .Net 4.0, is there a way that I can duplicate this functionality?

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="upPockets" updatemode="Conditional" >
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel ID="panPockets" runat="server" Width="100%" >
                         <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plPockets" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
                      </asp:Panel>
                     </ContentTemplate>
               </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide some code to show what was working that isn't working after you upgraded?

Comment: Thank you! There really isn't any code. I had the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback at the top of the page and that seemed to do it automatically.

Comment: Maybe this will help 
                      <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="upPockets" updatemode="Conditional" >
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel ID="panPockets" runat="server" Width="100%" >
                             <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plPockets" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
                          </asp:Panel>
                         </ContentTemplate>
                   </asp:UpdatePanel>
The placeholder gets dynamically filled with buttons and those button presses is when the page doesn't save the location and zoom

Comment: @JesseSmith Also, is there any easy way to copy code into here? And how do I get around the limit?

Comment: Instead of putting the code in a comment, edit your original question. That way, you can use the built-in code formatting tools that SO provides!